# TabBar is covering the TableViewController's TableView (Swift Solution needed)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I see that this questions has been asked before and answered; however, in objective-c.  I tried but could not convert it.  Any help is appreciated. This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f); 
}
```

The first line was easy:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.All
```

The rest, I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to uncheck under bottom bar of the tableViewController in storyboard.

Comment: tabBar height is 49, so you can try self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0.0,49, 0.0);

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I solved the problem by using a TableView inside a ViewController. That way I could set the constraints however I want.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this, then you don't need to use the TableView inside of a UIView.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.bounds.height
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.All
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: tabBarHeight!, right: 0.0)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, I think he should mark it as an answer